# dataframe2delta: how to plot a delta function directly from the dataframe using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I looked for an answer throughout the former threads, but with no luck.
I was wondering if it could be possible, given a data frame having a structure similar to this one

```
df <- data.frame(x = rep(1:100, times = 2 ),
                 y = c(rnorm(100), rnorm(100, 10)),
                 group = rep(c("a", "b"), each = 100))
```

to plot directly the difference, between the observations of the two groups, instead of plotting the two samples using different colours, which is what I'm able to do so far using ggplot2. Of course I know I could do that using the base plotting system by simply using

```
plot(df[df$group == "a",]$y - df[df$group == "b",]$y)
```

but doing so I waste all the cool features of ggplot2.

Thanks in advance!

EB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another possibility using `dplyr` is the following:

```
ggplot(df %>% group_by(x) %>% summarise(delta = diff(y)), 
       aes(x = x, y = delta)) + geom_line()
```

In this case you can avoid the `dcast` using the function `diff` and assuming the order between the groups, otherwise you need to sort the factors or apply a `dcast` on your data frame. I am quite sure that you can do something very similar using `data.table`.

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this:

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
df <- dcast(df, x~group, value.var='y')
df$dif = df$a-df$b
ggplot(df, aes(x, dif)) + geom_line()
```

Or if you use `data.table` here is how to do it:

```
library(data.table)
dt=data.table(df)
dt<-dcast.data.table(dt, x~group, value.var='y')
dt[,dif:=a-b]
ggplot(dt, aes(x, dif)) + geom_line()
```

How does this look?[image]

Comment: Not bad. And you think this is the most straightforward way to do this?Any chance the same thing could be done using either plyr or dplyr?

Comment: I am sure there is way to use `plyr` or `dplyr` but I am a user of `data.table` myself. I have edited my answer to include this method too, but it is not exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

It's not completely solved, but it looks close to what I meant:

```
qplot( x = x,
       y = diff,
       data = dcast( data = df,
                     value.var = y,
                     formula = x ~ "diff",
                     fun.aggregate = function( x ) x[1] - x[2] )
```

It's quite tricky and strongly depends on what you have in your `group` variable, but works.

An alternative was to mutate the output of dcast, but in my case the `group` column was filled in with `TRUE` and `FALSE`values. Thus, using mutate to obtain `diff=TRUE-FALSE` returned a column of 1s, not very useful.